# Removing index.php from url using htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url

Hello friends I am trying to remove `index.php` from my website URL, it is not working
to do that I have used `.htaccess` file, Is there something i am doing wrong

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Is your website working without the `index.php` from the URL?

Comment: no , it is showing error
forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

After adding index.php , it works fine

Comment: How did you setup your website? What web server are you using (apache or nginx)?

Comment: Do your URLs otherwise route OK?

Comment: Why didn't you use _virtual host_ for prevent this issue. it is simple and easy solution or try with https://gist.github.com/Guley/6b114d33eb7420a0a07d58670d965a8c , i mostly use this

Comment: @PHPNinja How would using "virtual host" prevent this issue? The linked code on github looks to be fundamentally the same as in the question?

Comment: @MrWhite Link is alternate solution. first is to create a virtual host and set directory location to `public` folder

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This instructs mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for `index.php` when requesting a directory. If this is not set appropriately or `index.php` is not found in the requested directory then you'll get a 403 response.

This is often already configured on most servers, however, the Apache default is `index.html` only. If this is left as default then you'll get a 403 when requesting the homepage.

Your "front-controller" is relying on the `DirectoryIndex` being set correctly.